# Div Lights Fade Script - Not working on Mac?

Tags: javascript, css, html, light

I have a little javascript/css script that fades my website to black, except for the video in the middle, to give a sort of theatre effect

Example  : http://www.animefushigi.com/bleach-episode-293

Click LIGHTS OUT

The script adds a black overlay on the entire page except for the "vidboxx" div.

Some people say that it is working, but not for me

Screenshot
http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/5963/firefoxscreensnapz002.png

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Could give some hints about what particular browser/platform you're using?

Comment: Mac OS X - firefox. I've tried on firefox, safari, and google chrome, all give me the same results....complete black overlay rather than the video div staying lit.

Comment: it does not work at all, as I can see it. May be You could post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add a z-index to "vidboxx", which is higher than the z-index of black overlay. Example:

```
#black-overlay: z-index:100;
#vidboxx      : z-index:101;
```

with Javascript, z-index is accessible by `yourelementhere.style.zIndex`